# Change the formatting of a variable in pyspark show()

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, format

I need to format the count value of group by in pyspark

```
df.groupBy('PURCHASE').count().show()
```

```
|PURCHASE| count|
+--------+------+
| 202003|1426702|
| 202002|281184 |
| 202001|94333  |
```

I want to show the count column with comma as thousand separator

```
|PURCHASE| count  |
+--------+--------+
| 202003|1,426,702|
| 202002|281,184  |
| 202001|94,333   |
```

Tried the below but getting TypeError

```
df.groupBy('PURCHASE').count().withColumn('cnt','{:,}'.format(F.col('count'))).show()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-936d1cb519c9> in <module>
----> 1 df.groupBy('PURCHASE').count().withColumn('cnt','{:,}'.format(F.col('count'))).show()

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Column.__format__
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `format_number()` [function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#format_number(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20int)) in Spark:

It formats a column to a format like '#,###,###.##', rounded to 'd' decimal places. In our case, we need `0` decimal places.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("count", format_number("count",0)).show()
+--------+---------+
|PURCHASE|    count|
+--------+---------+
|  202003|1,426,702|
|  202002|  281,184|
|  202001|   94,333|
+--------+---------+
```

It is good to note that it returns the result as a string.